# Cannot open Android SDK Manager or Android Emulator Manager after new installations

Tags: windows-7, java, android

Today I installed the Xamarin Studio 5.1 update for Windows. Afterwards, I installed all of the latest API's and build tools in the Android SDK Manager. Now the Android SDK Manager or the Android Emulator Manager will not open. Can someone please help?

Comment: Are you seeing an error when you try to launch?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and finally managed to solve it. I then created a step-by-step guide containing the universal fix to help all developers get past this issue asap: http://www.dominantwire.com/2015/03/android-sdk-not-opening.html

All the steps in short:

1.If you have jdk v1.8. Remove it and re-install jdk v1.7.x.x

2.Set paths to jdk and jre bin folders in the environment variables

3.delete (make a backup first) the .android folder present in C: > Users > [user-name] > .android

4.Set the JAVA_HOME variable keeping JAVA_HOME as the variable name and the path to bin folder of jdk as the variable value.

5.Go to [sdk-directory] > tools. Find and right-click on android.bat file and select 'edit' to open it in notepad and make the following modifications.

**ORIGINAL**

```
set java_exe=
call lib\find_java.bat
if not defined java_exe goto :EOF
```

**MODIFIED**

```
set java_exe=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe
rem call lib\find_java.bat
rem if not defined java_exe goto :EOF
```

*NOTE : Copy and paste your own java.exe path directory as explained previously.*

**ORIGINAL**

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('"%java_exe%" -jar lib\archquery.jar') do set swt_path=lib\%%a
```

**MODIFIED**

```
rem for /f "delims=" %%a in ('"%java_exe%" -jar lib\archquery.jar') do set swt_path=lib\%%a
set swt_path=lib\x86_64
```

*NOTE : If your android sdk is 64bit then mention set swt_path=lib\x86_64 otherwise if it is 32bit then keep it as set swt_path=lib\x86*

6. Done! Fire up android sdk from android.bat file or from eclipse. It should open up just fine!